# Excel load range into array, convert and return to original range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I'm reading a range into an array, looping through the array to value some formulas, and then returning the array to the worksheet. If I return the array to a different range than the original range then it appears to work OK, but if I return it to the original range I just get the first formula line rather than the whole range. What am I missing?

```
Sub Test2()
Dim vInArrayF As Variant
Dim vInArrayV as Variant
vInArrayF = Range("B13:M55").Formula
vInArrayV = Range("B13:M55").Value
Dim OutRange As Range
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long
For R = 1 To UBound(vInArrayF, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.
    For C = 1 To UBound(vInArrayF, 2) ' Second array dimension is columns.
        If Left(vInArrayF(R, C), 3) = "=+S" Then
            vInArrayF(R, C) = vInArrayV(R, C)
        End If
    Next C
Next R
'Set OutRange = Range("AB13:AM55")
Set OutRange = Range("B13:M55")
OutRange.ClearContents
OutRange = vInArrayF
```

End Sub

Comment: What do you mean by " I just get the first formula line"?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems that when you use vInArrayV = Range("B13:M55").Value, as you only take the value of the range vInArrayV will be an array and not a range. So OutRange = vInArrayF just copy the first element of the array hence the first formula.

Comment: You should be able to do it by looping through the rows and columns and put the value in the range with OutRange.cells(i,j) = vlnArrayF(i,j)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Range.Formula2`.

- `Range.Formula` applies the first formula to the whole column.
- `Range.Formula2` applies each the formula for every element in the array.

---

```
Sub ReplaceSomeFormulas()
    Dim vInArrayF As Variant
    Dim vInArrayV As Variant

    With Range("B13:M55")
        vInArrayF = .Formula2
        vInArrayV = .Value
        Dim R As Long
        Dim C As Long
        For R = 1 To UBound(vInArrayF, 1)
            For C = 1 To UBound(vInArrayF, 2)
                If Left(vInArrayF(R, C), 3) = "=+S" Then
                    vInArrayF(R, C) = vInArrayV(R, C)
                End If
            Next C
        Next R
        .Formula2 = vInArrayF
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks TinMan, but I get "Object doesn't support this property" on the vInArrayF = .Formula2 line.

Comment: @Paul the object is  `Range("B13:M55")`.  It should support the property.  Are you using a really old version of Excel?